# 30% users have remained idle to your Saas Product, what to do?

Tags: analytics, product-management

What do you do as product owner / founder when the metrics shows 30% of your customer who have paid subscriptions in your Saas Product, have not logged in to use your products for more than 3 months. What are the steps you take to know the reason. Is it just a customer survey or are their other ways of handling this issue.

Comment: Are they month-to-month subscriptions, or annual?

Comment: Also would be helpful to know the core of your product's offering. What are users logging in to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can't really work out the reason because there isn't any data from the users that you can use. However, there are ways you can get to the bottom of the root cause depending on where you want to start.

Firstly, you'll have some data from current users to see if the 70% of the users who are not idle are having a good user experience. You can separate them into those that are frequent users and those who are close to being idle. You'll want to use a combination of analytics and actual user research to validate your assumptions about why they are using or not using the product.

Secondly, you'll probably have some clues from the last time that the idle users have interacted with the product to see if there are any common trends or patterns. For example, maybe they stopped using the product around a certain period of time, or a certain number of activities. There might have even been some feedback or support ticket indicating that there were some issues, and they haven't been resolved.

Finally, you can reach out to them directly to offer genuine support and interest, since they might be on a subscription model and just paying for something that they are not using.

So just because you don't hear from your customers or users, there are still plenty of ways to find some questions and answers. But this should be a proactive step on the part of your business, rather than something that you do in reaction to a high proportion of idle users.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the product & market.
Is usage every 3 months normal for your product / market?
If so, and they're paying, sounds like everything's working.

If you want to increase adoption, a common approach is email feedback loops.
Ex. "hey, don't forget about this X benefit you get from our product X."
This invites the user back into the product while reinforcing the value.